# How to show that two objects of a monoidal category are dual to each other, given an adjunction between their functors of left tensoring.

Tags: category-theory

Suppose given a monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$ and $x,y \in \mathcal{C}$ and suppose that $x$ is the left dual of $y$ in the usual sense, $x = {}^*y$, i.e. there exist a unit $u\colon1 \to y \otimes x$ and a counit $e\colon x \otimes y \to 1$ that satisfy the snake identities
$$
(e \otimes 1_x)(1_{x} \otimes u) = 1_x, \\
(1_y \otimes e)(u \otimes 1_y) = 1_y.
$$
From this it is straightforward to deduce an adjunction $L_x \dashv L_y$ where for $z \in \mathcal
C$ $L_z$ is the functor of left tensoring with $z$.

Now it is often stated that such an adjunction is actually equivalent to $x$ being the left dual of $y$.
However trying to prove the converse I run into a problem. If $\eta$ and $\varepsilon$ are the unit and counit of the adjunction then the obvious choices for the unit and counit of the should-be duality $x={}^*y$ are $u = \eta_1$ and $e=\varepsilon_1$. When trying to proof the first snake identity it quickly follows that $\varepsilon_x(1_x\otimes \eta_1) = 1_x$. So to deduce the snake identity we need that $\varepsilon_x = \varepsilon_1 \otimes 1_x$. (And we need $\eta_y = \eta_1 \otimes 1_y$ for the other identity).

All functors $L_z$ are canonically right module functors $\mathcal C \to \mathcal C$ with respect to the canonical right $\mathcal{C}$-action of $\mathcal C$ on itself. The above conditions on $\varepsilon$ and $\eta$ mean precisely that they are module-natural transformations with respect to the canonical structures. It seems like it should be a rather obvious thing if it is true but I am unable to deduce this from the given adjunction. So how does it follow?

Comment: This is remarked on in the nlab page for dualizable object (remark 2.3 [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizable+object)). I suspect that the extra equations you need are equivalent to the condition mentioned there ("one also needs that the adjunction between these functors is preserved by tensoring with $A$").

Comment: Thanks, it helps to know that I'm not the only one wondering here :) If the assertion is not true, do you know of any counter example?